# How work with large data in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, listview

How can I solve this problem would in android ?

```
07-07 14:44:58.122: E/CursorWindow(12281): Could not allocate CursorWindow '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.mytestlistview/Mafatih/Mafatih.db' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
```

I create a `SearchBox` on a DB that it is `10MB` .That show the results of search on `ListView` but get me this error.

My StructNote.java :

```
public class StructNote {
    public String Title;
    public String Comment;

    public StructNote(String Title,String Comment)
    {
        super();
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Comment = Comment;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return Title;
    }


    public String getComment()
    {
        return Comment;
    }
}
```

My MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String DIR_SDCARD = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    public static final String DIR_DATABASE = DIR_SDCARD + "/Android/data/";
    public ArrayList<StructNote> notes = new ArrayList<StructNote>();
    public ArrayAdapter adapter;
    public String Titel_Drawer;
    public Integer titleID;
    public Cursor cursorid;
    public ArrayList<String> array;
    public static String PACKAGE_NAME;
    EditText editText;
    DB db = new DB(MainActivity.this);
    public Cursor cursor;
    public SQLiteDatabase sql;
    public ListView lstContent;
    int selectedId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        File file = new File(DIR_DATABASE + PACKAGE_NAME + "/Mafatih");
        file.mkdirs();
        db.GetPackageName(PACKAGE_NAME);
        db.CreateFile();
        try {
            db.CreateandOpenDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sql = db.openDataBase();

        final ListView lstContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContent);
        adapter = new AdapterNote(notes);
        lstContent.setAdapter(adapter);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        if (editText.getText().length() < 2) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter more text !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            populateListView(editText.getText());
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                        adapter.clear();
                        return false;
                        }
                return false;
            }
        });

        final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Language);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                Log.i("xxx", String.valueOf(selectedId));

            }
        });
    }

    public void populateListView(Editable editable) {
        if(selectedId == 2131034177)
        {
        try {
            cursor = sql.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM WebSite_MetaDataDBBack WHERE Comment LIKE '"
                            +"%"+ editable + "%'", null);
            array = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        StructNote note = new StructNote(Titel_Drawer, Titel_Drawer);
                        note.Comment = cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex("Comment"));
                        titleID = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex("CategoryID"));
                        cursorid = sql.rawQuery(
                                "SELECT Title FROM WebSite_CategoryBack WHERE CategoryID ="
                                        + titleID, null);
                        if (cursorid != null) {
                            do {
                                cursorid.moveToFirst();
                                note.Title = cursorid.getString(cursorid
                                        .getColumnIndex("Title"));
                            } while (cursorid.moveToNext());
                        }
                        notes.add(note);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                cursor.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("xxx", "You have an error");
        }

        }
        else if(selectedId == 2131034176)
        {
            try {
                cursor = sql.rawQuery(
                        "SELECT Tafsir,CategoryID FROM WebSite_MetaDataDBBack WHERE Tafsir LIKE '"
                                +"%"+ editable + "%'", null);
                array = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (cursor != null) {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            StructNote note = new StructNote(Titel_Drawer, Titel_Drawer);
                            note.Comment = cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex("Tafsir"));
                            titleID = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex("CategoryID"));
                            cursorid = sql.rawQuery(
                                    "SELECT Title FROM WebSite_CategoryBack WHERE CategoryID ="
                                            + titleID, null);
                            if (cursorid != null) {
                                do {
                                    cursorid.moveToFirst();
                                    note.Title = cursorid.getString(cursorid
                                            .getColumnIndex("Title"));
                                } while (cursorid.moveToNext());
                            }
                            notes.add(note);

                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    cursor.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("xxx", "You have an error");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My AdapterNote.java :

```
public class AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter<StructNote> {

    public AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> array) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.dapter_notes, array);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtTitle;
        public TextView txtDescription;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        }

        public void fill(ArrayAdapter<StructNote> adapter, StructNote item,
                int position) {
            txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
            txtDescription.setText(item.Comment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        StructNote item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.dapter_notes, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My G.java :

```
public class G extends Application{
    public static Context context;
    public static LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

And this is my Db.java for DB :

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{   
    public static final String DIR_SDCARD =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    public static final String DIR_DATABASE = DIR_SDCARD +"/Android/data/";
    private static  String DB_NAME = "Mafatih.db";
    private final Context myContext;
    public static String PACKAGE_NAME;
    public boolean flag = false;

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DIR_DATABASE +PACKAGE_NAME+"/Mafatih/"+ DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        try{
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Copy", e.toString());
        }
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

       }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DIR_DATABASE +PACKAGE_NAME+ "/Mafatih/" + DB_NAME, null, 0);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
         Log.e("asdf", "checkDataBase-->"+e.toString());
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
       }
    @Override
    public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
        return super.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    public DB(Context context) {
     super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }   


    public void CreateandOpenDataBase() throws IOException{
         boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
         if(dbExist){
         }
         else
         {
        try {
                copyDataBase();
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database --> "+e.toString());
            }
         }
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        return SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DIR_DATABASE +PACKAGE_NAME+ "/Mafatih/" +DB_NAME, null);
       }


    public boolean CreateFile(){
        if(flag == false)
        {
            File file= new File(DIR_DATABASE);
            file.mkdirs();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void GetPackageName(String res){
        PACKAGE_NAME = res;
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have closed the cursor.

Comment: Yes.I can mail my sample project for you.

Comment: No , just post that snippet here.

Comment: @Jefferson Update the question with the code snippet.

Comment: @Jefferson yes just code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** `Could not allocate CursorWindow '.....' of size 2097152 due to error -12.`

**Reason:** Most of the times this issue arises due to non-closure of cursors. You must close all the cursors after using them.

In your code if any exception occurs in try block, the cursor will not be closed as control will be passed to catch block. Hence modify your code as follows:

```
try {....}
catch{
}
finally {
   cursor.close();
}
```

It is always a good practice to close the `cursor` in `finally` block.

You are not closing `cursorid` too. Make sure you close `cursorid` too.

**UPDATE 1:**

> Why and when does this exception occur?

For processing an SQLite statement, a memory area is created by SQLite, known as context area, which contains all information needed for processing the statement, for example, number of rows processed, etc.
A cursor is a pointer to this context area. SQLite controls the context area through a cursor. A cursor holds the rows (one or more) returned by a SQL statement. The set of rows the cursor holds is referred to as the active set.

[Cursor.close()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close%28%29) closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making it completely invalid.

So if you do not close the cursor, the resources most importantly the memory pointed by cursor is not released and it causes leak which in turn causes allocation issues.

Hope it helps.